# JSON encoding problems with bash scripting

Tags: json, bash, encoding, github

I'm trying to create a script to automate issue posting on GitHub, but I'm having problems with JSON encoding.
I want to use the content of a file as the body of the issue. The pertinent file has multiple lines and some special characters. When I run the following script it creates the issue successfully on GitHub but the body of the issue appears messed up. All the lines of the file ends up being concatenated and special characters are not displayed correctly.

Is there a way to fix this? Below is my code, thanks!

```
FILES=*

for f in $FILES; do
    if [ $f == "script" ]; then 
        continue;
    fi

    body=$(cat $f)
    echo "{\"title\": \"title\", \"body\": \"$body\"}" > body.temp
    curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "$1:$2" -d @body.temp -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/$f/testing/issues
    rm -rf body.temp
done
```

Comment: example inputs and outputs would probably help. Post an issue using the github UI, and compare its body with the one you get when posting using your script.

Comment: let's say i post the issue "a\nb\nc\n" using the UI, with the script it would result in "abc" altogether.

Comment: AFAIK, the body of an issue is rendered using markdown, and if you want a line break once rendered, then it should have two successive line breaks between the lines in the body.

Comment: You should probably quote `"$(cat $f)"` Also, you should definitely remove the `-r` flag from `rm`

Comment: @BroSlow, didn't work.

Comment: Try quoting $f as well since it's processed in a subshell `"$(cat "$f")"` You also definitly need to quote `"https://api.github.com/repos/$f/testing/issues"`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/), you will see that a string can contain **any Unicode character except for `"`, `\`, and control characters** (when un-escaped).

I can't comment on github's JSON parser specifically, but you almost certainly want to escape the file content. Here's how you might use a Perl one-liner in the loop body to perform the escaping:

```
body=$(perl -ne 'chomp; s/\\/\\\\/; s/"/\\"/g; print $_ ."\\n"' $f)
echo "{\"title\": \"title\", \"body\": \"$body\"}" > body.temp
```

Testing it:

```
$ cat >somefile
a
"b"
\c
$ body=$(perl -ne 'chomp; s/\\/\\\\/; s/"/\\"/g; print $_ ."\\n"' somefile)
$ echo "{\"title\": \"title\", \"body\": \"$body\"}" > body.temp
$ cat body.temp
{"title": "title", "body": "a\n\"b\"\n\\c\n"}
```